# Benefits of defining classes for JSON Serialization?

Tags: json, typescript, serialization

I'll admit I haven't done a ton with this, as i've mostly written UI Automation code in the past. However more recently i've been working with API testing and JSON responses from endpoints.

I know that Serialization is a big topic, and for languages such as C# they have built in methods to (I assume) take a JSON request and serialize it into a class. Where im a bit lost however is how defining a class really helps outside of adding methods to it? Also why do I also see DTO's implemented as well on top of classes? (Isn't that sort of duplicating efforts or am I misunderstanding DTO's?)

Speaking of that however, for something like Typescript with an API Libary/Testing Library what benefits do I even gain to define classes/Interfaces/Types for a JSON schema/class that I might receive from an endpoint that provides a JSON response?

From my understanding any sort of "Type" inference is lost during run-time, so do I really gain any benefit from doing this?